# Distribute an incoming data stream into separate containers within the same network (Twitter API & AWS ECS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, twitter, streaming, amazon-ecs

I am building a data pipeline on AWS which streams the data from a Twitter's v1.1 [POST statuses/filter](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/filter-realtime/api-reference/post-statuses-filter). A streamer app sits within an ECS (i.e. docker) container from which it sends the initial POST request. The app then sends the tweets to an AWS Kinesis Firehose stream (so it's possible to send the data to the same KF stream from different places/agents).

I am using a VPC, hence it's possible to run multiple containers within the same network.

The question is: **Is it possible to distribute an incoming (Twitter) data stream into multiple containers within the same network (VPC)? And if yes, any hints how to do that?**

**UPD.** My pipeline is `Twitter API -> [ECS container] streamer app -> S3 -> Lambda (predictions) -> Elasticsearch`, and I'm talking about the streamer app part.

The ultimate goal here is to be able to scale depending on the intensity of the stream. E.g., have one small (memory, CPU) container when the traffic from Twitter is low and spin up more of them when the stream is more intense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is possible (equating one streamer to one Twitter API connection), but that will give you the exact same stream returning the same Tweets in each streamer instance.

If you're tracking a static set of keywords, a good approach would be to autoscale to a single larger container, instead of having additional container ingesting the exact same stream in parallel.

Comment: I was asking rather whether it's possible to somehow connect to the running Twitter stream from the same network but a different container. I don't quite get the other approach though. My pipeline is now `Twitter API -> [ECS container] streamer app -> S3 -> Lambda (predictions) -> Elasticsearch`. The streamer is used solely for reading from the Twitter stream and moving the tweets to S3. Why would I need the `Lambda -> S3 -> CloudWatch -> DynamoDB` loop?

Comment: If the streamer is needed to move the tweets to S3, then your architecture is good to go!

Comment: Yep, but what I'm looking for is to scale the streamer (`Twitter -> S3`) on demand with ECS (to spin up more containers to process the same data stream from Twitter when the traffic is high, e.g. a spike in my keywords tweet number). And I'm asking if it's possible to do that.

Comment: That is possible (equating one streamer to one Twitter API connection), but that will give you the exact same stream returning the same Tweets in each streamer instance. If you're tracking a static set of keywords, a good approach would be to autoscale to a single larger container, instead of having additional container ingesting the exact same stream in parallel.

Comment: I see. Yes, what you suggest seems like a nice tactic. Like, whenever I get `IncompleteRead` from Twitter, I spin up a larger container. Sounds good, thanks!

Comment: Thank you! I'll update the answer based on your feedback.